# How to search for AWS resources by tag substring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, tags, substring, wildcard

I'm trying to obtain a list of all AWS resources that have a particular tag whose value contains a particular substring.

*Reason: Our resources are all tagged with `ServiceName` but for some of these more than one service is applicable. In these cases the applicable services are listed in the tag value, e.g. `ServiceName: Service1 / Service2 / Service3`.*

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-management-console-update-tag-substring-search/) seemed very promising... but it seems the functionality in it has since been removed from the Tag Editor, at least from the front-end (would be very interested to know if it still exists in the back-end and could be possibly still accessed by "hacking" the URL???)

I also looked at the [get-resources CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html) but this doesn't seem to provide wildcard or substring filtering either.

Open to any other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Think I've finally got there with the AWS CLI:

``` aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[?(@.Tags[?Key==``ServiceName``&&contains(Value,``Service1``)])]' ```

The above is using a [JMESPath expression](https://jmespath.org/) via the [`--query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side) parameter.